# How can I add multiple FlowDocumentReaders to a StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

Thanks to [Leom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287912/how-can-i-add-a-flowdocument-to-a-stackpanel/2287970#2287970) I was able to add a **FlowDocument** to a **StackPanel** by wrapping it in a **FlowDocumentReader**.

But now I have two problems:

- it seems **only the first** FlowDocumentReader is added and the rest ignored
- there is an **unwanted margin** that I can't get rid of

**How can I add multiple FlowDocumentReaders to a StackPanel without the unwanted margin?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1ndiqqe.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1ndiqqe.png)

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestFlowdoc23432.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="200" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainArea"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace TestFlowdoc23432
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();

            TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
            tb1.Text = "first text block";
            sp.Children.Add(tb1);

            TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
            tb2.Text = "second text block";
            sp.Children.Add(tb2);

            sp.Children.Add(GetFlowDocumentReader("first flow document reader"));
            sp.Children.Add(GetFlowDocumentReader("second flow document reader"));

            MainArea.Content = sp;
        }

        FlowDocumentReader GetFlowDocumentReader(string text)
        {
            FlowDocumentReader fdr = new FlowDocumentReader();
            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
            fdr.Document = fd;
            fdr.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
            par.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            fd.Blocks.Add(par);

            Run r = new Run(text);
            par.Inlines.Add(r);

            return fdr;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the text appear to the left you need to set the pagepadding property on your flowdocument as follows:

```
fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(0);
```

the reason that you only seem to get the first reader is becuase it fills the space available (move it to be the first object and you will not see the textblocks). 
If you change the FlowDocumentReader to be a FlowDocumentScrollViewer and use the VerticalScrollBarVisibility property then you can get the desired effect.  The following is your GetFlowDocumentReader method with the changes applied:

```
FlowDocumentScrollViewer GetFlowDocumentReader(string text)
        {
            FlowDocumentScrollViewer fdr = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();

            FlowDocument fd = new FlowDocument();
            fdr.Document = fd;
            fdr.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            Paragraph par = new Paragraph();
            par.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            fd.Blocks.Add(par);

            Run r = new Run(text);
            par.Inlines.Add(r);

            fd.PagePadding = new Thickness(0);
            fdr.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;

            return fdr;
        }
```